# textbox formatting

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, format, design-patterns

I need some help with my code.

I need the following format,

> 12345-1234567-1

Basically I want to type just digits and when text length reaches 5, it should append '-' and again on reaching to the length of 13, again it should append '-'.

My code is doing this fine. But when I use backspace/delete, it always append '-' to the 6th and 14th location.

Here is my code,

```
private void nicNo_txt_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() != "Back" || e.KeyCode.ToString() != "Space" || e.KeyCode.ToString() != "Delete")
        {
            if (nicNo_txt.TextLength == 5 || nicNo_txt.TextLength == 13)
                nicNo_txt.AppendText("-");
        }
    }
```

Regards

Comment: What about if you use the Mask and DisplayFormatString properties. Set it to: #####-#######-#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried MaskedTextBox, in it you can specify a mask in whatever format you need

Comment: Thanks for the help. Two more things, One "can i remove underlines when it asks for input" and two "when cursor reaches '-' location it should move next to '-', similarly when i use backspace it should move previous to '-'. I hope you understand what i mean. Just like when entering windows serial while installation (just with difference that there you have multiple textboxes)

Answer (score 1):

One below will do

For formating after changes - replace format method with anything you like:

```
    void oTextBoxAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (sender is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            tb.Text = FormatAmount(tb.Text);
            tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

For filtering keys (example below filters digits but you can change conditions):

```
    void oTextBoxAmount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int val = (int)e.KeyChar;
        if (val >= 0x30 && val <= 0x39)
        {
            //Digits are ok
        }
        else if (val == 0x08)
        {
            //Backspace is ok
        }
        else
        {
            //Other are disallowed
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX Control Toolkit's Masked Edit. It does exactly what you want.

[Ajax Control Toolkit - Masked Edit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)